# Developing Enterprise Device Management Service for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am starting to develop EDM service.

To start with How can I create Enrollment Discovery.svc service?

Are there any tutorials/articles available which can guide me for development of complete Enterprise Management Service?

These days I am going through WP8 Enterprise Device Management Protocol document.

Answer (score 0):

That document is the only one available on this topic. Ensure that you have the latest one as it fixes some typos in older ones.

Answer (score 0):

The Discovery.svc should support both HTTP GET and POST. GET should give 200K which is an indication for the Wp8 device that the server is active and then tries to do POST on the Discovery service with SOAP request.

I would suggest you to develop a sample server (not necessarily in .NET but on any convenient platform). Note that its not mandatory for you to have only a .Net server. You could create a dummy server that listens on a port and ip adress and makes decision based on the URL path value. Once you fix the dicovery receipt on the server side, rest of the links to be posted in POST response i.e., certificate policies request and Enrollment request are completely in your hands.